# Is there an algorithm to go from a Context-sensitive grammar to a linear bounded automata?

Tags: theory, automata-theory

I am studying LBA (linear bounded automata). Trying to figure it out how to solve some exersise.

So I wonder if there is an easy way to make a LBA given a Context-sensitive grammar.

This is thinking like how you can go from LR grammar to DFA (deterministic finite automata).

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since context sensitive grammars don't have any contractive production rules, you can just use exhaustive search.

Starting with a string, you can non-deterministically select a production to undo.  This cannot increase the length of the input.  Repeat until you either reach the empty string (in which case you accept) or cannot undo any production (in which case you reject).

This is a sketch, but filling in the details is straightforward.